# Can't acces a string in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a function that should read a csv file and then process it so I can use it to generate an HTML table. Basically the output of the function should be a multidimensional array that looks like this : `[["prop", "type"], ["prop", "type"]...]`

The problem is that when e.g. I try to access to `"prop"` using `importProps[0][0]`, it will actually output a `"p"`. The weirdest thing is the output of the console in the two last lines of the function; I consider them as being the same thing, but they deliver a different output. I don't understand why I can't access to the whole string like on the `console.log(elem[0])` line.

Here is my code.

```
function importProperties() {
    //read the data
    var importProps = readTextFile(getProjectDirectory() + '/test.csv'); //outputs ["prop; type", "prop; type"...]
    // process it to become [["prop", "type"], ["prop", "type"]...]
    for (var i = 0; i < importProps.length; i++) {
        var elem = importProps[i].split(';');
        importProps[i] = elem;  
        console.log(elem[0]); // Outputs $"prop" 
        console.log(importProps[i][0]); // Outputs $"p" <--WHY ? 
    }
```

My original loop was

```
for (var i = 0; i < importProps.length; i++) {
    importProps[i] = importProps[i].split(';'); 
}
```

which produces the same unexpected result. I just added the element variable for debugging purposes.

By the way, I'm writing this in a software-embedded browser which communicates with the software through a provided API. The console in this browser has only very limited capabilities and makes it hard to do some proper debugging.

Comment: This is working fine for me.  Are you sure `readTextFile` is working correctly?

Comment: Yes it is. Actually I couldn't upload the complete code but readTextFile() is a method of an API (that I can't show online, corporate privacy). Normally its xxxAPI.readTextFile () and xxxAPI.getProjectDirectory(). Do you get the two same outputs in the console ? Can you access the whole `prop` string using `importProps[0][0]`. Thanks.

Comment: Copy and pasting your code into the Chrome console, then replacing `readTextFile` with `["prop; type", "prop; type"];`, outputs `prop prop prop prop`.  Logging `importProps[0][0]` gives `prop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The browser that is embedded in the software is actually based on Webkit. After I've tried pasting the code in Firefox as suggested by Mike, I got to the same conclusion as he did : it worked perfectly.

After a little research and multiple `typeof` statements, I found where the problem came from. It actually came from the `importProps[i] = elem;` line. `elem` is an array here (`typeof` outputs `object`) while `importProps[i]` is a string (`typeof` outputs `string`). After I assign `elem` to `importProps[i]`, `importProps[i]` is still a string ! (`typeof` returns `string`).

```
for (var i = 0; i < importProps.length; i++) {
    var elem = importProps[i].split(';');
    importProps[i] = elem;
    console.log(typeof importProps[i]); // Logs 'string'!!! Firefox logs 'object' here
    console.log(typeof elem);           // Logs 'object' 
};
```

That is not the case in Firefox, and I don't know why this behavior has been implemented to Webkit. The solution was finally to create a multidimensional array and assign the split string to it.

```
function importProperties() {
    //read the data ["prop;type", "prop;type"]
    var importProps = xxxAPI.readTextFile(xxxAPI.getProjectDirectory() + '/test.csv');
    //process to be [["prop", "type"], ["prop", "type"]...]
    var importPropsArray = [[]]
    for (var i = 0; i < importProps.length; i++) {
        var elem = importProps[i].split(';');
        importPropsArray[i] = elem;
    };
    return importPropsArray;
};
```

I don't know if this is kind of a bug or a desired behavior, but it's very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly I am not allowed to comment :(
The code runs fine in console and provides what you asked for.

My guess would be that in the real code you assigned the string instead of the array **importProps[i] = elem[0];**

```
var importProps = ["prop; type", "prop; type"];
for (var i = 0; i < importProps.length; i++) {
    var elem = importProps[i].split(';');
    importProps[i] = elem[0]; //Maybe you have this line live instead of importProps[i] = elem;?
    console.log(elem[0]);
    console.log(importProps[i][0]);
}
```